# Oracle Dual vs Sys.Dual

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am using Oracle as a back end for my asp.net project. I have a user named Test. All the sequence worked fine `(select seq_name.nextval from dual;)` but now I cannot access dual directly (the sequence only work when I say `select seq_name.nextval from sys.dual`.So now I have to use sys.dual. This also caused the function `ORA_ASPNET_CREATEUSER` function (asp.net membership) to become invalid since I guess it also uses dual rather than sys.dual.

Any clues?

Comment: Just create a synonym test.dual for sys.dual

Comment: someone dropped the public synonym. Nasty!

Comment: thanks a lot... so oracle already has the public synonym dual, which someone dropped, and I have to recreate it. ok

Comment: I'm surprised things aren't crashing left and right without dual.  This is the kind of error that demands an investigation; how would such a thing happen, and what else was broken?  Less seriously, if you really want to cause trouble, `insert into dual values('X');`